# Cygwin not installing packages properly?

Tags: cygwin

I installed wget and unzip using the setup.exe but it doesn't seem to be installed, instead i get 'command not found'. The cygwin/bin folder doesn't have both wget or unzip. I tried different mirrors to download, I guess that's not the issue. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your `$PATH` set up correctly? Did you change the Cygwin installation directory when you ran `setup.exe`?

Comment: yes my PATH is set correctly. When i ran setup.exe, it gives option to set local package directory but my cygwin installation directory is the same, unless I am not understanding what you mean by that.

Comment: Are you attempting to run wget/unzip via the Cygwin shell or in a Windows command shell?

Comment: Are you sure you selected wget and unzip for installation? (They are not in the default base install).  Otherwise, it might be helpful to look in  /var/log/setup.log for anything relating to those packages

Comment: Accept your answer, if it had worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I did everything correctly except when I ran the setup.exe, by default 'Download without installing' was selected. Switched to 'Install' option and its working.